# Zero Diffraction Plates: Why do they give such low diffraction signals?

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

In our laboratory we use silicon plates named "Zero Diffraction Plates". They are named so because they give extremely low diffraction signals in an XRD instrument (reflection mode). But how are these plates made to ensure such low signals?

I heard they are cut at a specific atomic layer in the crystal; this layer then becomes the surface. Do diffraction on this layer lead to destructive interference at all possible irradiation angles? I would like to at least have a phenomenological understanding of how this works, and I hope someone is able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, from some online forum: the Si is cut on the 5-1-1 plane (not a layer but an orientation).   How this orientation leads to zero (or minimal) diffraction is a nasty problem in solid geometry, I fear.  For example, here's [a paper](http://www.rigaku.com/downloads/journal/Vol17.1.2000/yang.pdf) which discusses a variety of diffraction situations in gory detail.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to destructively interfere for all angles, just avoid constructively interfering for all angles that are possible ($0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$).

The (typically silicon) crystal is cut so that the crystallographic planes parallel to the surface have an interplanar spacing below that accessible with the radiation wavelength used. The limiting value of this corresponds to $\sin\theta=$ in Bragg's law, yielding $d_{min}=\lambda/2$. For a typical Cu $K\alpha$ source, $\lambda = 0.15418\,\mathrm{nm}$, this limit would be at $d_{min}=0.0771\,\mathrm{nm}$.

The interplanar spacing of the $\{9 1 1\}$ planes of silicon is $d=\frac{a}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2+l^2}}=\frac{0.543}{\sqrt{83}}=0.060\,\mathrm{nm}$.
For the $\{5 1 1\}$ planes suggested elsewhere the interplanar spacing is $0.105\,\mathrm{nm}$, accessible with Cu $K\alpha$ but only at $95^\circ$ which is at the edge of the useful range on benchtop diffractometers.